# Inject an array inbetween another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to merge (inject) an array in between another array. 
Injected array is adding an additional level at the top.

Actual code is different, but here I have created a simple example to illustrate the issue I am facing.

Here is the sample code:

```
$mid_array = [
  'heading3'  => 'Heading 3',
  'heading4'  => 'Heading 4'
];

$main_array = [
    'heading1'  => 'Heading 1',
    'heading2'  => 'Heading 2',
    $mid_array,
    'heading5'  => 'Heading 5'
];

echo '<pre>'; print_r($main_array); echo '</pre>';
```

Output I am getting

```
Array
(
    [heading1] => Heading 1
    [heading2] => Heading 2
    [0] => Array
        (
            [heading3] => Heading 3
            [heading4] => Heading 4
        )

    [heading5] => Heading 5
)
```

This is what exactly I need

```
Array
(
    [heading1] => Heading 1
    [heading2] => Heading 2
    [heading3] => Heading 3
    [heading4] => Heading 4
    [heading5] => Heading 5
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the assumption that your arrays might change but will continue to have keys like heading1, heading2 this would be my solution

```
$newArray = array_merge($main_array,$mid_array);
ksort($newArray);
```

this will return the array you need.

Comment: Keys are completely dynamic and ksort will change their location. 
Also, in actual implementation, there will be many instances where arrays have to be injected in the main array.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `array_splice`, as such:

```
array_splice($main_array, 2, 0, $mid_array);
```

Note: `array_splice` does not preserve keys, if keys are important to you, use following:

```
function array_insert(&$input, array $arrayToAdd, int $atPosition) {
    $before = array_slice($input, 0, $atPosition, true);
    $after = array_slice($input, $atPosition, null, true);
    $input = $before + $arrayToAdd + $after;
}
```

**Usage**

```
array_insert($main_array, $mid_array, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `array_merge` functionality.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$after = 'heading2';
$result = array_reduce(
    array_keys($main_array),
    function ($carry, $key) use ($main_array, $after, $mid_array) {
        $carry[$key] = $main_array[$key];

        return $key === $after
            ? array_merge($carry, $mid_array)
            : $carry;
    },
    []
);
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5e231b41d5afcedeaa41bd9ffcd2faca5dee80c3).

Answer (score 0):

If key ordering presents a problem (with something like array_merge) you can flatten the inserted array by walking it recursively.  You walk along the tips plucking what you need as you go.

```
<?php
$insert = [
  'foo'  => 'And it\'s been the ruin of many a poor boy',
  'bar'  => 'And god I know I\'m one'
];

$inserted = [
    'big'  => 'There is a house in New Orleans',
    'fat'  => 'They call the rising sun',
    $insert,
    'mama'  => 'My mother was a taylor'
];

$flattened = [];
array_walk_recursive(
    $inserted,
    function($v, $k) use (&$flattened) {
        $flattened[$k] = $v;
    }
);
var_export($flattened);
```

Output:

```
array (
'big' => 'There is a house in New Orleans',
'fat' => 'They call the rising sun',
'foo' => 'And it\'s been the ruin of many a poor boy',
'bar' => 'And god I know I\'m one',
'mama' => 'My mother was a taylor',
)
```